# Resize MUI Drawer from the right side

Tags: material-ui, drawer

I'm using Material ui Drawer and I want to make it resizable. I used this CodeSandbox to make it resizable and it works. The thing is that in the Sandbox the Drawer is on the left side and in my own code the Drawer is on the right side. So now the resizing goes in the opposite direction as my mouse moves. How/where can I fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/resizable-drawer-forked-w6ki9?file=/src/CustomDrawer.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Position the dragger on the left hand side (`left: 0` instead of `right: 0`). Change the resize function to:

```js
document.body.offsetLeft + document.body.offsetWidth - e.clientX + 20
//                 scrollbar width - varies on different browsers! ^
```

This is basically changing it from `x` to `100% - x`. Et voilà! https://codesandbox.io/s/resizable-drawer-forked-3e6po