# How to resize an MUI Drawer horizontally & resize the rest of the layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've looked at some Stack Overflow answer and kind of tried to get halfway there.
I need an MUI drawer on the left that when you open it the drawer is resizable horizontally and that when you make it bigger or smaller, that the rest of the view resizes to accommodates. Unfortunately I can't use grid. I feel like there has to be a better.

This Stack Overflow question:

- [Resize MUI Drawer from the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518156/resize-mui-drawer-from-the-right-side)

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/resize-mui-drawer-336c2d?file=/demo.tsx
There is a bit of a weird thing going on as well and I'm not sure how to fix it. Like when I  mouse up it'll sometimes resize it until I click somewhere random and then if I reclick in the right area it'll kind of resize right again.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dragger: {
    width: "5px",
    backgroundColor: "#f4f7f9",
    cursor: "ew-resize",
    padding: "4px 0 0",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: 100
  }
}));
export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const minDrawerWidth = 50;
  const maxDrawerWidth = 1000;

  const [drawerWidth, setDrawerWidth] = React.useState(50);

  const handleMouseMove = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const newWidth = e.clientX - document.body.offsetLeft;
    if (newWidth > minDrawerWidth && newWidth < maxDrawerWidth) {
      setDrawerWidth(newWidth);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp, true);
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, true);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp, true);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, true);
  };
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <DrawerHeader>
        <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
          {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
            <ChevronRightIcon />
          ) : (
            <ChevronLeftIcon />
          )}
        </IconButton>
      </DrawerHeader>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
            <ListItemButton
              sx={{
                minHeight: 48,
                justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                px: 2.5
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon
                sx={{
                  minWidth: 0,
                  mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                  justifyContent: "center"
                }}
              >
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
            <ListItemButton
              sx={{
                minHeight: 48,
                justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                px: 2.5
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon
                sx={{
                  minWidth: 0,
                  mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                  justifyContent: "center"
                }}
              >
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  // https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2h1g6x?file=ResponsiveDrawer.js
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => handleMouseMove(e));
  //   document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => handleMouseUp(e));
  // }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 5,
              ...(open && { display: "none" })
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Mini variant drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        open={open}
        PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }}
      >
        <div
          id="dragger"
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            handleMouseDown(event);
          }}
          className={classes.dragger}
        />
        {drawer}
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
          integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate
          eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo
          quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat
          vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
          lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
          elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse
          sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat
          mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis
          risus sed vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas
          purus viverra accumsan in. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non
          tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique
          sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis
          eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla
          posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same issue :(

Comment: @Leonardo I did not but I went with an alternative that worked alright. I replaced the drawer with a simple div and the inner of the div had some MUI components
.drawer{
  display: flex;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: min-content;
  max-width: 50%;
}